# TinyTDS: offset removes aggregate function from select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sql-server, tiny-tds

I have the following query

```
User.select('first_name, MAX(created_at)').group(:first_name).order(:first_name).offset(10)
```

This gives me the following error

> TinyTds::Error: Column 'User.created_at' is invalid in the select list
>   because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the
>   GROUP BY clause:
>
> **EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP (10) [__rnt].* FROM ( SELECT
>   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY type ASC) AS [__rn], first_name,
>   created_at FROM Users GROUP BY first_name ) AS [_*rnt] WHERE
>   [*_rnt].[_*rn] > (10) ORDER BY [*_rnt].[__rn] ASC'**
>
> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: TinyTds::Error: Column
>   'User.created_at' is invalid in the select list because it is not
>   contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.:
>
> **EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP (10) [__rnt].* FROM ( SELECT
>   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY type ASC) AS [__rn], first_name,
>   created_at FROM [Users] GROUP BY first_name ) AS [_*rnt] WHERE
>   [*_rnt].[_*rn] > (10) ORDER BY [*_rnt].[__rn] ASC'**

Why is the above query generated without the MAX on created_at?

When i run the same query without the `offset`, everything is fine. The following query runs fine and it retains the MAX on created_at

```
User.select('first_name, MAX(created_at)').group(:first_name).order(:first_name)
```

Also, this is a problem only with sql server. If i run the same in postgres or mysql, it works fine.

Is this a known issue with TinyTDS? How can i solve this problem?

Update:

I found the lines causing my issue

`lib/arel/visitors/sqlserver.rb(line 373)`(activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-3.2.10)

```
# TODO: We use this for grouping too, maybe make Grouping objects vs SqlLiteral.
  def projection_without_expression(projection)
    Arel.sql(visit(projection).split(',').map do |x|
      x.strip!
      x.sub!(/^(COUNT|SUM|MAX|MIN|AVG)\s*(\((.*)\))?/,'\3')
      x.sub!(/^DISTINCT\s*/,'')
      x.sub!(/TOP\s*\(\d+\)\s*/i,'')
      x.strip
    end.join(', '))
  end
```

Comment: Are you sure this is the result SQL statement? In your example you have `offset(2)` but in the generated SQL statement you have `[_rnt].[_rn] > (10)`? Also, could you please check the if the following two are workings `User.offset(3).limit(1)` and `User.limit(1).offset(3)`?

Comment: It should have been offset(10). Modified my question. Both   `User.offset(3).limit(1)` and `User.limit(1).offset(3)`. Problem is not with `offset` or `limit`. Problem comes up when i use aggregate function in select with group by(without the column used in aggregate) and offset. Offset somehow removes the aggregate function which makes group by invalid

Comment: I am pretty sure you are not going to find help here - please prepare example and post it here https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter

Comment: Before do that, could you try `User.select('first_name, MAX(created_at) as created_at').group(:first_name).order(:first_name).offset(10)`?

Comment: @gotqn: Error: `TinyTds::Error: Column 'User.created_at' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.: EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP (9223372036854775807) [__rnt].* FROM ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY type ASC) AS [__rn], first_name, created_at as created_at FROM [Users] GROUP BY first_name ) AS [__rnt] WHERE [__rnt].[__rn] > (10) ORDER BY [__rnt].[__rn] ASC'`

Comment: Can you check if `User.maximum("created_at").group(:first_name).order(:first_name)` and if to add the offset too?

Comment: `User.maximum("created_at")` returns a Time object. When i do `User.maximum("created_at").offset(10)` I get `NoMethodError: undefined method offset for 2013-11-25 23:58:00 UTC:Time`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41998/discussion-between-vimsha-and-gotqn)